# Creating linked list with multiple element types

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

My C course had its in class final last week, and we still have 1 more week worth of classes before the end of the semester and my professor decided on cancelling the rest of the classes.

I had asked him why he wasn't using that time to teach us linked lists and he said "The final was already given so there is no need for me to teach anything else".

I still want to learn linked lists and now since my professor isn't of any use I want to ask you kind people to help me with an application I was thinking of.

Simply put, I have a text file with lines like so:

```
Apple     //name   
12        //quantity   
23.90     //price   
Bananas   //name  
4         //quantity  
12.90     //price
```

I understand how to read the above txt file into an array of structures but I don't understand how to do the same with linked lists.

My structures example:

```
typedef struct
{
char food_name[BUF];
int food_quantity;
float food_cost;
}FOOD;
```

I would love to post the rest of my code as an example but since I still have 2 years left of college and also having that same professor mentioned above for the next 3 semesters, I don't want to risk academic dishonesty and potential next year students taking my homework answer (gl on HW3 if anyone from this class next year sees this)

Comment: Your structure is not a chain in a linked list. A linked list has a pointer to the next element in the list. `struct food_s { .......; struct food_s *next; }`

Answer (score 0):

A linked list of your structure has an additional pointer to the next structure to connect one structure to the next. A simple single linked list looks like:

```
typedef struct food_s {
  char  food_name[BUF];
  int   food_quantity;
  float food_cost;
  struct food_s *next;
}food_t;
```

This is only the little beginning, but there are several books describing linked list, double linked lists, binary trees etc. sorted lists, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some *rough* code to get you started, I'm being lazy and neglecting to free the allocated FOOD memory.

I learn best when tracing through examples. I'll encourage you to pay close attention to the values displayed by the pointers (the **%p** in the various printfs). For example, where does **next=0xa22070** come from in *name="Cherries" qty=8 cost=1.23 next=0xa22070* ?

Pointers and memory management will become increasingly important as you get into more advanced code for all kinds of data structures (linked lists, trees, queues).

Good luck with your learning curve :-)

### output

```
$ gcc food.c 
$ ./a.out
--- directly calling print_food() ---
FOOD addr=0xa22010  name="Apple" qty=12 cost=23.90 next=(nil)
FOOD addr=0xa22070  name="Bananas" qty=4 cost=12.90 next=0xa22010
FOOD addr=0xa220d0  name="Cherries" qty=8 cost=1.23 next=0xa22070
--- calling print_food_list() ---
food list #001: FOOD addr=0xa220d0  name="Cherries" qty=8 cost=1.23 next=0xa22070
food list #002: FOOD addr=0xa22070  name="Bananas" qty=4 cost=12.90 next=0xa22010
food list #003: FOOD addr=0xa22010  name="Apple" qty=12 cost=23.90 next=(nil)
Done, n=3
$
```

### food.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF 64

typedef struct food
{
   char  name[BUF];
   int   quantity;
   float cost;
   struct food  *next; // ptr to next food, otherwise null.
} FOOD;

FOOD *make_food(char *name, int quantity, float cost, FOOD *next) {
    FOOD *p = malloc(sizeof(FOOD));
    strcpy( p->name, name);
    p->quantity = quantity;
    p->cost = cost;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}

void print_food(FOOD *p) {
    printf("FOOD addr=%p  name=\"%s\" qty=%d cost=%.2f next=%p\n",
        p, p->name, p->quantity, p->cost, p->next);
}

int print_food_list(FOOD *p) {
    int length = 0;
    while( p ) {
        ++length;
        printf("food list #%03d: ", length); // note lack of \n
        print_food(p);
        p = p->next;
    }
    return length;
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FOOD *a = make_food( "Apple", 12, 23.90, (FOOD *)NULL );
    FOOD *b = make_food( "Bananas", 4, 12.90, a);
    FOOD *c = make_food( "Cherries", 8, 1.23, b);
    printf("--- directly calling print_food() ---\n");
    print_food(a);
    print_food(b);
    print_food(c);
    printf("--- calling print_food_list() ---\n");
    int n = print_food_list(c);
    // int n = print_food_list(a); // what would happen with a?
    printf("Done, n=%d\n", n);
}
```